# Regex allows for repeating the pattern when I don't want it to

Tags: regex

I'm trying to take a query parameter and verify if the syntax provided by the user is correct. Regex seems like the best choice for this, but I'm having trouble making it so the pattern doesn't allow for repeating itself.

The pattern I came up with is:

```
(^(\w+)(=|!=|>=|>|<=|<|~)((')(.*)('))(\s(AND|OR)\s)(\w+)(=|!=|>=|>|<=|<|~)((')(.*)('))$)
```

The syntax provided by the user should to be:

> [field][predicate][single quote][value][single quote][white space][logical operator][white space][field][predicate][single quote][value][single quote]

Where:

1. field is [any word]
2. predicate is [= | != | >= | > | <= | < | ~]
3. logical operator is [AND | OR (with a space on both sides)]
4. value is [any word wrapped by single quotes]

> An example looks like this: **field1='value1' OR field2='value2'**

The problem I am having is that the pattern I created allows for things like this:

> field1='value1' OR field2='value2field1='value' OR field2='value2'' [**This shouldn't work but does**]
>
> field1='value1' OR field2='value2 field1='value' OR field2='value2'' [**This shouldn't work but does**]
>
> field1='value1' OR field2='value2' AND field3='value3' OR field4='value4'' [**This shouldn't work but does**]

Any help would be appreciated making it so the pattern doesn't match if it repeats.

Comment: java `!=` javascript. Please select one language and remove the other one.

Comment: I edited the post. Only regex now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use:

```
^\w+(?:<=|=>|!=|[~<>=])'\w+'(?: (?:OR|AND) \w+(?:<=|=>|!=|[~<>=])'\w+')*$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `\w+` Match 1 or more word chars
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `<=|=>|!=|[~<>=]` Match one of the alternatives
- `)` Close group
- `\w+` Match 1 or more word chars between single quotes
- `(?:` Non capture group
- `(?:OR|AND) \w+` Match space, either `AND` or `OR` and 1+ word chars

  - `(?:<=|=>|!=|[~<>=])` Match one of the alternatives
  - `\w+` Match 1 or more word chars between single quotes
- `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times to also match without `AND` or `OR`
- `$` End of string

If there should be at least a single `AND` or `OR` the quantifier of the last group could be `+` instead of `*`

The single chars in the predicate could be added to a character class `[~<>=]` to take out a few alternations.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2k5KWn/1)

Comment: Hey forth bird, thanks for the reply. I tested this out and it seems to  work for most of my use cases. However it doesn't work for something like this: field='word with spaces' or things like dates: dateLastModified='2019-09-10T14:30:04.000Z'. Any suggestions?

Comment: @DanWhitehouse You could for example use a negated character class to match any char except a newline between the double quotes https://regex101.com/r/vDPzNa/1

Comment: @theforthbird that's perfect!  Thank you so much! I was about to  try something like: ^\w+(?:<=|=>|!=|[~<>=])'[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.:\s]+'(?: (?:OR|AND) \w+(?:<=|=>|!=|[~<>=])'[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.:\s]+')*$ but what you did was much nicer. :-)